# Change all buttons to "working" in jquery.ajaxStart and back to "Save" in jquery.ajaxStop

Tags: jquery

I would like to change the text on my buttons (which are actually divs) to "Working" when an ajax request is processing. I'd also like to disable them from being clicked again until the ajax process is over. When it is, I'd like to enable the button and change the text back to "Save".

I was thinking of using the JQuery .ajaxStart() and .ajaxStop() global events to handle this. Something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#btnSave').each(function() {
        $(this).data('eventsbackup', $(this).data('events'));
        $(this).data('events', null);
        $(this).html('Working...');
    });
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $('#btnSave').each(function () {
        $(this).html('Save');
        $(this).data('events', $(this).data('eventsbackup'));
        $(this).data('eventsbackup', null);
    });
});
```

Do you see anything wrong with this approach? I'm a little worried about setting .data('event') to null instead of using unbind(), but I can't be sure how many events are  bound to the buttons. Could this approach cause problems?

Comment: What kind of buttons are you talking about? Like `button` or `input` elements or like archors?

Comment: They are divs that look like buttons and are bound via Jquery to JavaScript functions which call Jquery.ajax().

Comment: I can tell you that stuffing the 'events' into a backup variable isn't working. It's still firing the event when I click the button again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see one big problem, you're using **ID's** rather than **classes** so only the **FIRST** button will likely be affected.

Change the buttons to use classes and then your jQuery to `$(".buttons").each()`

As for enabling/disabling buttons why not use a `is-disabled` data attribute on your buttons and test for it inside your click functions. Something like this

```
<a href="#" id="get-files" class="button">Get Files</a>
<a href="#" id="get-folders" class="button">Get Folders</a>
```

**Sample click code**

```
$("#get-files").click(function(e) {
    var isDisabled = $(this).data("is-disabled");
    if(!isDisabled) {
        // run Ajax Code
    }
}); // Do the same for #get-folders, even better wrap it in a reusable function
```

**Then with your existing code just do**

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('.button').each(function() {
        $(this).data("is-disabled", true);
        $(this).html('Working...');
    });
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $('.button').each(function () {
        $(this).html('Save');
        $(this).data("is-disabled", false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems more like a comment and not like an answer though.

Comment: Changing the buttons is not an option as you suggest because I have about a thousand click events I'd have to change. This is a big application. That's why I'd like to do this globally.

Comment: Oh I didn't see the part about editing every click event, however you could add a global handler to all buttons with that condition or put it in the `.ajaxStart()` I guess.